# .htaccess, https redirects to login.php

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is the [link](http://ineedcrew.com.au) of the website.

Another domain hosted on the same server needs to be redirected to the login.php page and I am not the developer nor I have the knowledge of how that redirection is made. Yet I have to stop being redirected to the `login.php`. Is there a way to achieve this by `.htaccess`?

I actually want to enable https only on the home page and the signup page, which I can do with a HTTPS plugin. When I enable them, as I stated they go to the login.php file...

Important note: the link/domain above doesn't have an ssl configured but the other domain which needs to be redirected has it. But they have a CA bundle installed on the server.

Second important note: I actually need this to pass the data with https to securely use the fb - twitter - linkedin login buttons.

I'd be very glad for any advice. Thanks for your time!

Edit #1 - the other domain mentioned above has only these on the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your redirect rule to come **Before** your wordpress routing rules. Otherwise the route happens first, rewriting whatever URL you requested, then the second rule redirects the internal route.

Try:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried that too, but still doesn't solve the issue :/ I'm adding the .htaccess of the other domain (which normally should be the only one redirecting).

Comment: @Ekin have you cleared your browser's cache? a 301 redirect is permanent so your browser is going to always use its cache.

Comment: Sure, I cleared it. One thing weird... I don't recognize any redirection code for /login.php/ in any of the .htaccess files. Can you tell me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Ekin it's probably index.php redirecting then.

Comment: Okay just checked and there are two index.php files in the 2nd domain. One of them is looking irrelevant though. Preparing a pastebin. Edit- added pastebin

Comment: @Ekin look at line 25 and 36 of your log.php file. If you don't want the internet to see your php code, you should remove the pastebin entries

Comment: Right... I commented those out but it's still redirecting.